# Connecting to a local network Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a:

`Rasberry Pi 2`

running

`Raspbian Jessie Version:November 2015`

I am using Undertow (a Java http server) to serve a website. This is the code that I use to build the server.

```java
Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                   .addHttpListener(8890, "localhost")
                   .setHandler(Handlers.pathTemplate()
                      .add("/", resource(new PathResourceManager(staticFilePath, 100))
                              .setDirectoryListingEnabled(false))
                   .build();
```

Problem: I am unable to see the webserver from another machine on the local network despite being able to ping and SSH into the PI.

What I have done (on the Pi2):

`wget localhost:8890`

returns the index.html correctly

`netstat -lptn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8890          :::*                    LISTEN      1743/java
```

Chrome on my development machine 192.168.1.8:8890 gives
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

`wget 192.168.1.8:8890`

Connecting to 192.168.1.8:8890... failed: Connection refused.

`nmap 192.168.1.8`

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-05 14:05 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.8
Host is up (0.039s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.83 seconds
```

It is my understanding that there is no firewall so I am baffled as to why I can't see the server from my development machine.

Comment: Try nmap from your host to discover what ports are visible.

Comment: Your nmap scan you've posted wouldn't show it open anyway, the default scan only scans 1,000 ports. You can see that by it saying 999 closed and showing 22 open. That's because the most common services create sockets in the reserved range of 0-1024.

If you wanted to scan for that specific port, try nmap -p 8890

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8890    :::*      LISTEN      1743/java
```

Your web server listens only on localhost address (127.0.0.1). This way it couldn't be accessed from anywhere but localhost.

And your nmap scan shows the same: the only remotely accessible port is 22.

To access this service remotely you have to bind web server to any non-local address belonging to this raspberry pi (192.168.1.8) or to "any address" 0.0.0.0, as SSH service is bound.

How to do this is written in the manual of your web server. Probably, you have to start is with a "-d" param, i.e.

```
standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

or something like this.

In listener setup code this looks like

"localhost" have to be replaced with some public name. This could be "0.0.0.0" or "192.168.1.8". We also can

```
cat "192.168.1.8 somename" >> /etc/hosts
```

and then use somename:

```
Undertow server = Undertow.builder() .addHttpListener(8890, "somename")
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Undertow and so I manually set it.  Other than setting it in my code are there additional steps?

Comment: The only wrong thing I see in your question is that web server was bound only locally. I don't know about your code, if it checks remote address on its own, you might need to configure it to allow access from other addresses.

Comment: I am using Undertow not the bundled version that ships with JBoss.  I have a single line for the binding that looks like this `Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8890, "localhost");

Comment: Yes, this is the source of your problem. You have to change "localhost" to some public name. Try to specify IP address (0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.8) there instead. If this won't work, cat "192.168.1.8 somename" >> /etc/hosts on raspberry pi, and then use this "somename" instead of localhost.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I will fix and mark this as correct answer.  Will you add that comment to the answer?

Comment: Yes, please tell, which variant exactly did helped you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97117/discussion-between-nikita-kipriyanov-and-nathaniel-johnson).