# Connecting devices on a local network

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, local-network

I am trying to connect send HTTP request from my raspberry pi to a server running on my laptop. First, I tried to connect using `127.0.0.1`. The connection was refused. Next, I looked at the IP my laptop is using for the WiFi and modified my server to listen on that address and raspberry pi to send request to that address which is `192.168.X.X`. Finally, I modified the `/etc/hosts` file on both raspberry pi and my laptop after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110061/connecting-to-a-local-network-raspberry-pi). I am still getting connection refused.

What I need is to be able to send HTTP requests from my pi to my laptop over local network. I am using a `nodejs` client on pi to send the request. I am using `express` server to listen for the request. What configurations do I need to setup such a local network environment?

Comment: Are you using the port in the URL while using the wifi ip for laptop.

Comment: @Vishwanath I am trying to connect to port 4201. I added that to the urls: `127.0.0.1:4201` and also `192.168.X.X:4201`

Comment: Is your request directed to: `http://192.168.X.X:4201/endpoint`?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy Yes. `http://192.168.X.X:4201/tick`

Comment: Have you checked your firewall in your laptop?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy It was a problem with `firewalld`. Disabling it worked. Thanks

Comment: No worries; I've stumbled upon my own firewall quite a lot of times so far :)